# How to specify more than one string to ignore (grep command)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I am using grep to filter out directories I am not interested in like this:

```
svn stat | grep -v data/charts | grep -v lib/model | grep -v web/pics
```

It seems a bit "hacky". Is there a better way to specify more than one string to ignore, so that I dont have to chain multiple grep commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `svn stat | grep -vE 'data/charts|lib/model|web/pics'`

You may also be interested in looking at `grep -x`. `ack` might be another tool of interest to you.

Comment: This is the command that works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use disjuction with grep. Its the pipe symbol like in many regexes but you have to escape it since bash interprets it as actual pipe. Try this:

```
svn stat | grep -v data/charts\|lib/model\|web/pics
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use grep -f, and put the list of patterns into a file. (That's most convenient if the list of things is fairly constant, of course.) grep -vf works fine, and inverts the sense of the matching just like regular grep -v. Just make sure you don't have any blank lines in the file full of patterns, because they'll match everything!